# Extracting one plot from the plot function in geoR

Tags: r, plot, geor

I am using the `geoR` package, and I would like to display only one of the graphs obtained when using the `plot` function. Using a dataset provided with the package:

```
library(geoR); data(elevation)
plot(elevation)
```

This gives 4 plots on a 2 x 2 grid as in below. I would like to use the bottom right plot alone, but I am not sure how to get this plot alone.

[image]

So I tried plotting it from scratch:

```
axExFact <-1.1 # to set fitting y-axis limits
ymax <- max(c(0, signif(max(elevation[[2]])*axExFact, digits=1)))
ymin <- min(c(0, signif(min(elevation[[2]])*axExFact, digits=1)))


with(elevation, hist(data, main='Plot', xlab = 'Value ',cex.lab=1.25,  font.lab=2,ylim=c(ymin, ymax)))
```

Though I can get the y-axis limits adjusted to fully cover the extent of the data, I am unable to add a density estimate along the histogram. Thought it could be done with `lines(density(as.numeric[[elevation]]))`, but it doesn't work.

So it would be a lot easier to just get the graph obtained with the `plot` function. Then the only problem would be to adjust the y-axis. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: You could use `with(elevation, { hist(data, prob=T); lines(density(data)); rug(data) })` to reproduce this plot. If you really want to extract one plot you have to play with the return value of `?recordPlot` but IHMO it is not worth the effort. I would suggest to draw this plot by your own.

Comment: THanks sgibb. That will work fine for me. Thanks again